# How can I make the object called "player" to stop moving its shape when i go up and right (it then goes diagonally and faces up/down/r/l depending)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> ```
> private GameObject player;
> ```

```
//the CharacterController is used to make sure that it just focuses changes on this specific character
//can get rid of it to make a generalised movement of characters.
CharacterController myCharController;

[Header("Character Settings")]


[SerializeField]
private float PlayerSpeed = 5.0f;
private float turnSpeed = 20f;
private float RunningSpeed = 7.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float JumpSpeed = 7.0f;

private const float gravity = 25.0f;
//public float Speed { get; private set; } = 0.0f;

private Vector3 move;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    myCharController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    move = Vector3.zero;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Movement();
    rotate();
}

void Movement()
{
    if (myCharController.isGrounded)
    {
        move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f);
        move *= PlayerSpeed;
        move = transform.rotation * move;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            move.y = JumpSpeed;
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * JumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }

    move.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    myCharController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);

}
void rotate()
{ 
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0));
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, 0));
}
```

This is my code. The problem is that when I move my mouse on the screen then the character goes in the same direction however when i make a circle motion or just go up/down and right/left with the mouse the characters body is going horizontal or diagonally. (i don't know if that makes sense. Hope it does.)

I thought it was because of the Vector3, however any change i was making to it(changed it into being Vector2) didnt work at all. I was trying to make a limiter to it but I think I need to look over the "mathf clamp" before doing it and I think it might work. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to this by actually changing the way the character rotates. Instead I made the camera rotate and then transform the character in the same way the camera rotates allowing for it to happen.